# R language: how to work with dynamically sized vector?

Tags: r

I'm learning R programming, and trying to understand the best approach to work with a vector when you don't know the final size it will end up being. For example, in my case I need to build the vector inside a `for` loop, but only for some iterations, which aren't know beforehand.

METHOD 1

I could run through the loop a first time to determine the final vector length, initialize the vector to the correct length, then run through the loop a second time to populate the vector. This would be ideal from a memory usage standpoint, since the vector memory would occupy the required amount of memory.

METHOD 2

Or, I could use one `for` loop, and simply `append` to the vector as needed, but this would be inefficient from a memory allocation standpoint since a new block may need to be assigned each time a new element is appended to the vector. If you're working with big data, this could be a problem.

METHOD 3

In C or Matlab, I usually initialize the vector length to the largest possible length that I know the final vector could occupy, then populate a subset of elements in the `for` loop. When the loop completes, I'll re-size the vector length appropriately.

Since R is used a lot in data science, I thought this would be a topic others would have encountered and there may be a best practice that was recommended. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just grow to fit. I know that isn't ideal but I don't usually see a huge performance difference unless there's a _ton_ of iterations.

Comment: I think there is a fourth approach that is sometimes used. Allocate the vector (assuming we are talking about the general notion of "vector" that R uses) in medium-sized chunks and then allocate another chunk inside the loop, if it's not enough. Disadvantage: Process can halt prior to completion. Advantage: Partial results could be available.

Answer (score 2):

Canonical R code would use `lapply` or similar to run the function on each element, then combine the results in some way.  This avoids the need to grow a vector or know the size ahead of time.  This is the functional programming approach to things.  For example,

```
set.seed(5)
x <- runif(10)

some_fun <- function(x) {
  if (x > 0.5) {
    return(x)
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
}

unlist(lapply(x, some_fun))
```

The size of the result vector is not specified, but is determined automatically by combining results.

Keep in mind that this is a trivial example for illustration.  This particular operation could be vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

I think Method1 is the best approach if you have a very large amount of data. But in general you might want to read this chapter before you make a final decision:

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html